# Euclidean metric of 3D space

Tags: spacetime, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

For 3D Euclidean space, does the metric of space
\begin{gather}
\delta_{ij}=\mathbb{I}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
show that the unit vectors are orthogonal
\begin{gather}
\hat{e_i}\cdot\hat{e_j}=\delta_{ij}
\end{gather}

or does the fact that the unit vectors are orthogonal dictate what the metric of space must be?

Comment: Which came first, the chicken or the egg?

Comment: That's two ways of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Orthogonality is practical but not required. As long as the determinant of the matrix does not vanish all is well ...